# Kendo DropDown Javascript Error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

with this two Kendo DropDowns I get following Javascript error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function kendo.all.min.js:11

What is wrong?

regards

```
<div class="form-group">
    @* ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved *@
    <label for="for-date" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 control-label">@GlobalResources.ForDate</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("for-date")
            .DataTextField("Text")
            .DataValueField("Value")
            .AutoBind(true)
            .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetForDatesResidentTransmissions", "Report")).ServerFiltering(false))
        )
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @* ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved *@
    <label for="place-types" class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 control-label">@GlobalResources.PlaceType</label>
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
              .Name("place-types")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .AutoBind(true)
              .DataSource(source => source.Read(read => read.Action("GetPlaceTypes", "Report")).ServerFiltering(false))
              )
    </div>
</div>
```

## UPDATE

In the not minified JS File the error is thrown in this line:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function kendo.all.js:7406
>
> that._pristineData = data.slice(0);

Comment: Are you including jQuery (jquery.min.js)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this post: http://www.telerik.com/forums/error-rendering-data-with-autocomplete---object-object-has-no-method-'slice'---how-to-resolve-

I have found my mistake, the json object that I return has to wrong structure.